# Adding different Icon to Application

Tags: iphone

I want to support two different appln icon images, One is 57x57 and other is 114x114. 
How to decide which icon to use in case of iPhone3GS or lower and iphone4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to handle this yourself.

Just add both files as items in the "Icon Files" array in your app's info.plist using the @2x naming scheme for the high-res version and the right icon should be selected automatically.